# Regex to match phone number

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am looking for a regex to match `PH +46 11122233`. 
I have tried `[+][0-9]{2}\s\d{8}$` which matches `+46 11122233` but not `PH`. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: `PH  [+][0-9]{2}\s\d{8}$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
Regex.IsMatch("PH +46 11122233", "^PH \+\d{2}\s\d{8}$") 'True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this site
[Regexr](https://regexr.com/3c53v)
Or use something like this:

```
1[\s./-]?\(?[\d]+\)?[\s./-]?[\d]+[-/.]?[\d]+\s?[\d]+
phonenumber = '\n'.join([phone for phone in re.findall(r'1[\s./-]?\(?[\d]+\)?[\s./-]?[\d]+[-/.]?[\d]+\s?[\d]+' ,phonelist)])
print(phonenumber)
```